# How to print the memory location of a Ruby object

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to print out the memory location of a Ruby object, not from  `puts self` as I want to have a custom `to_s` method and print the memory pointer location as one of the pieces of information to be output.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't know why would you want such a feature, and this is *very* implementation-specific, but on MRI 1.9 you can (ab)use `object_id`:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :022 > class A; end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 > a = A.new
 => #<A:0xa2b72e4> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :024 > a.object_id.to_s(16)
 => "515b972" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :025 > (a.object_id << 1).to_s(16)
 => "a2b72e4"
```

For an explanation of why does it work, check out the [relevant lines](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/gc.c#3158) in MRI `gc.c`.

Note that this will not work on other implementations (JRuby, Rubinius), and may very well break in future versions of Ruby. Also, there may be no way at all to get the address in some implementations (I suspect that you cannot in JRuby; I'm not sure, through).

Comment: +1 You are correct, there is no way to get at the "real address" of any object in Java, and for good reason---the GC can move objects (for example, between young and old generations, if using a generational collector), and thus there is no way to get such a thing in JRuby either. Also, like you said, what's the point? The address is ephemeral at best, especially in implementations that use a moving GC.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Well, Im a newbie in this Ruby world and I was wondering whether I can make a custom to_s method for logging purpose to print the class name, instance address location and the entire instance variables with its values. Thanks a lot

Comment: for debugging purposes, you usually would use `inspect`.

Comment: If we're questioning why the OP wants to print memory location, maybe we should ask why MRI does it.

Comment: @Andrew, these memory locations in MRI provide absolutely no value on their own. IMO it would be better if `object_id` (which is at least well-defined in terms of Ruby) would be displayed instead.

Comment: The link is broken.